# Preserve x flag in file mode after downloading it from a website

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, executable, chmod

I put a Linux executable file on my website and I would like that, when someone downloads it on a Linux machine, it is still executable.

However, when the file is downloaded it loses the x flag. Is there a solution? Despite I had a look in many places, I didn't manage to find a solution for this issue.

It is particularly important for me because I would like the whole process to be extremely easy for everyone: my idea is allowing the users to right click on the file and choose "Run in terminal", without clicking before on "Permissions" and make the file executable and without `chmod +x filename` or `sh filename`

Comment: Downloading random executables over the 'net is a security risk. Besides, you are just downloading a file and storing it away as yourself here, noticing that the file was executable on the Windows box at the origin because it was called `something.exe` there can't be reasonably expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maybe group this file (and others) in a `tar` file. While donwloading it and un-taring it, permissions will be kept.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, actually this can be a nice solution.